# Refresh DIV container

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I wrote the code to refresh DIV container once function `click_function_ps()` is executed. But my code does not work. It says:

```
missing ; before statement
var newHTML = "<img class="displayed" src="ganttchart.php">";
```

So, where do I need to put `;` ?

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="regular" onclick="click_function_ps(); replaceContent();">
        <img src="images/opt.png" alt=""/> Run </a>
</div>

<div id="opt_container">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%">
                    <div class="scrollbar" id="chart">
                        <img class="displayed" src="ganttchart.php">
                    </div>  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceContent() {
     var newHTML = "<img class="displayed" src="ganttchart.php">";
     document.getElementById("scrollbar").innerHTML = newHTML;
}
</script>
```

Comment: var newHTML = '<img class="displayed" src="ganttchart.php">';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
var newHTML = "<img class=\"displayed\" src=\"ganttchart.php\">";
```

Also, there is no element with the ID `scrollbar`. Either change the DIV from `class="scrollbar"` to `id="scrollbar"` or use ID `chart` right away or replace the javascript by following `document.getElementsByClassName("scrollbar")[0]`. But keep in mind, that `getElementsByClassName()` is not supported by IE. I highly recommend using `id` instead of `class`.

Comment: Ok, but now it says: document.getElementById("scrollbar") is null, when I press "Run"

Comment: Yes,now there is no error (I used getElementById("chart") ), but the content of DIV becomes empty after pressing Run. I need to Ctrl+R to see the new chart. So, it seems that something else is left.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("chart").innerHTML += newHTML;`

Answer (score 1):

You haven't escape double-quote in this part :

```
function replaceContent() {
   var newHTML = "<img class=\"displayed\" src=\"ganttchart.php\">";
   document.getElementById("scrollbar").innerHTML = newHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try these: -

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a href="#" class="regular" id="scrollbar" onclick="click_function_ps(); replaceContent();">
        <img src="images/opt.png" alt=""/> Run </a>
</div>

<div id="opt_container">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%">
                    <div class="scrollbar" id="chart">
                        <img class="displayed" src="ganttchart.php">
                    </div>  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
function replaceContent() {
     var newHTML = "<img class=\"displayed\" src=\"ganttchart.php\">";
     document.getElementById("scrollbar").innerHTML = newHTML;
}
</script>
```

This type of error will not come if you will use any `IDE(netbeans etc)`..
Because `IDE` check your syntax error while your are doing code..

Comment: The problem is that now it says: document.getElementById("scrollbar") is null, when I press "Run"

Comment: where u defined your fun click_function_ps();